Why Mn in MnO2 has valence 4 while it is in 7th group?
If we look at its electrons, 4 of them are given to oxygen and 3 are unpaired probably in this substance. It doesn't seem an energetically good composition. Although, $\ce{MnO2}$ is very stable substance.
What is its electronic model and why it is energetically better than for example valence 5 when 2 electrons stay paired and 5 are given to oxygen as $\ce{Mn2O5}$?
UPD: Let's paraphrase the question: is it truth that unpaired electrons always cause less stable substances? Otherwise, how could we guess resulting substance from Mendeleev table if not by electronic model of atoms?

Manganese has a valence of 7. That's according to the definition of valence. That also does not change in whatever compound it's in. The concept of valence just isn't very useful. And simply because one thing is stable doesn't mean another can't be.

For transition metal compounds it doesn't really matter if they're dia- or paramagnetic.

Well, ok, let's use not valence (it's really not very close to reality, as it even doesn't have + or -). Let's talk about electrons. So, why 3 electrons become so stable in this substance?
Isn't it right for phosporus, P2O3 is more stable than P2O5 with 5 unpaired electrons?

"P2O3" is really P4O6 and has lone pairs, not unpaired electrons.

Manganese has the electronic structure of argon +  $7$ electrons. Apparently nobody is able to explain why and how manganese is stable at the oxidation number +$4$ in $\ce{MnO2}$

you are really talking oxidation state, not "valence". And stable manganese compounds are known with oxidation states from -3 to +7. There is no single one that is dominantly stable though some are more common that others.

Ok, I ask unanswerable questions hence. Well.
